# Renaming keys in an object using reduce method in JS

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, object, ecmascript-6

Following is the object in which I want to replace `countryID` with `value`, `countryName` with `label`.

In the same object I am having `localLanguages` Array in which I am trying to rename `language` with `label` and `languageCode` with `value`.

array -

```
var obj = [{
    "countryID": "CON1010",
    "countryName": "Poland",
    "countryCode": "pl",
    "localLanguages": [{
        "language": "English",
        "languageCode": "en"
      },
      {
        "language": "Polish",
        "languageCode": "en"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "countryID": "CON1011",
    "countryName": "UK",
    "countryCode": "uk",
    "localLanguages": [{
      "language": "English",
      "languageCode": "en"
    }]
  }
];
```

Transformed to -

```
var obj = [{
    "value": "CON1010",
    "label": "Poland",
    "countryCode": "pl",
    "localLanguages": [{
        "label": "English",
        "value": "en"
      },
      {
        "label": "Polish",
        "value": "en"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "value": "CON1011",
    "label": "UK",
    "countryCode": "uk",
    "localLanguages": [{
      "label": "English",
      "value": "en"
    }]
  }
];
```

Code -

```
arr.map(x => {
  var newObj = Object.keys(x).reduce((obj, key) => {
    if (key !== 'countryID') {
      obj[key] = x[key]
    }

    if (key === 'countryID') {
      obj.value = x.countryID;
    }
  }, {})
  console.log(newObj);

  return newObj;
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Array.map()` to convert the outer objects, and another map to convert the `localLanguages`:

```js
const arr = [{"countryID":"CON1010","countryName":"Poland","countryCode":"pl","localLanguages":[{"language":"English","languageCode":"en"},{"language":"Polish","languageCode":"en"}]},{"countryID":"CON1011","countryName":"UK","countryCode":"uk","localLanguages":[{"language":"English","languageCode":"en"}]}];

const result = arr.map(o => ({
  value: o.countryID,
  label: o.countryName,
  countryCode: o.countryCode,
  localLanguages: o.localLanguages.map(l => ({
    value: l.languageCode,
    label: l.language
  }))
}));

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is a solution with es6 Destructuring and map:

```
 const arr = [{"countryID":"CON1010","countryName":"Poland","countryCode":"pl","localLanguages":[{"language":"English","languageCode":"en"},{"language":"Polish","languageCode":"en"}]},{"countryID":"CON1011","countryName":"UK","countryCode":"uk","localLanguages":[{"language":"English","languageCode":"en"}]}];

 const result = arr.map(item => {

  let localLanguages = item.localLanguages.map(i => {
    const { language: label, languageCode: value, ...rest } = i;
    return { label, value, ...rest };
  });

  const { countryID: value, countryName: label, ...rest } = item;

  return { value, label, ...rest, localLanguages };
});

console.log(result)
```

Comment: It will be better to set the code in a function, after that it will be great if you can explain what is the meaning of each step so it will be clear what are the required changes in the code. Another thing - when manipulating an object it is better to use Object.assign({}, obj) so you are manipulating on a copy of the object.

Comment: @Rotem I've changed a bit the code for more clarifications, now you can run the code and see the result. I just iterated from the arr array and created a new array with the requirements in the question above.

Answer (score 0):

You have forgotten to return obj value in the reduce function

```
 var newObj = Object.keys(x).reduce( (obj, key) => {
    if(key !== 'countryID') {
      obj[key] = x[key]
    }

    if(key === 'countryID') {
      obj.value = x.countryID;
    }
  }, {})
```

Answer (score 0):

Here the function to change the keys. Use it with every element of you array
recursively, but check the type of every element

```
function changeKeys(obj) {
  const rename = {
    'countryID': 'value',
    'countryName': 'label',
    'language': 'label',
    'languageCode': 'value'
  }
  return Object.keys(obj)
    .reduce(
    (acc, rec) => {
      if (typeof rename[rec] !== 'undefined') {
        return {...acc, [rename[rec]]: obj[rec]}
      }
      return {...acc, [rec]: obj[rec]}
    }, {}
  )
}
```